# How to show NumPad on the Keyboard Viewer

Tags: macos, mojave, accessibility

I use a software which requires keyboard shortcuts on the NumPad.  The number keys above the keyboard won't work.  On a MacBook Pro, I used to be able to open the on-screen Keyboard Viewer and click on the keys, but it's not working in Mojave.  Now the on-screen keyboard mirrors the laptop keyboard, and only shows the NumPad if I connect a full-size USB keyboard.  How can I get the full-size virtual keyboard back?

[image]

Answer (score 10):

The can be done via a custom panel in the Accessibility keyboard.

[image]

Comment: This is really cool, I didn't know about this feature.  Unfortunately it doesn't work.  Clicking the NumPad numbers on this virtual keyboard sends the same key command as the top row of numbers.

Comment: @Elliot What is that software for which you need this?  Does their support have any ideas?